# Vaadin (7.0.5) Window not opening until end of calling procedure

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I am trying to open a modal window during a click handler to verify the user action but the window doesn't appear until the handler completes. The window code can be as simple as the following and it still will not display so it isn't something to do with my abstract class.

```
    Window w = new Window();
    w.setModal(true);
    w.setImmediate(true);
    // Add components etc etc

    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(w);
```

I could add the action code to the windows OK/Yes handler but that would stop me creating a generic Message class to simplify/stop code duplication.

I am guessing there is something I dont understand about how Vaadin/GWT works (still a newbie!), could someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UI stuff, you have to stop thinking of sequencial programming,
better to think about event-driven concepts.

For Vaadin you could create a Dialog Window which asks the yes/no question.
In you app you create this dialog and display it.
And you attach a event-handler which is fired when the user clicks yes/no,
and inside this handler you then do the required actions in your code.

You can also look at this add-on

https://vaadin.com/de/directory#addon/confirmdialog

Comment: Cheers. I realised how to tie my system together to make it work with the event driven model (while sat outside the pub this weekend!). It is taking a while to change my approach!

Answer (score 1):

The right direction is architecture overview https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/architecture.html#architecture.overview

In other words your code makes only response from server side, but only client side can show "modal" window.

In your case you have to create handler for ok button click event and wait for this event